# Is it possible to deploy elasticsearch in Webfaction?

Tags: web-server, django, elasticsearch

I'd like to deploy [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) (ES) at [Webfaction](https://www.webfaction.com/) server. I have 256MB of memory and running a Django app that takes about 100MB. I need to index about 10,000 records. Is it possible to run ES in a pool with about 128MB of memory?

Answer (score 0):

For just 10K documents I would say yes, but the best way to know is to try it. Remember to set `ES_HEAP_SIZE` to something sensible like 64Mb or it could happen that ES will grow to much in memory and the processes will be killed by Webfaction.